# Error when trying to unmask relay modern fragment that has arguments

Tags: relayjs, relay, relaymodern

I've got the following query:

```
query ChatRefetchContainerRefetchQuery(
  $arg: ID!
  $arg2: Boolean!
) {
  ...PeopleFragment
    @arguments(arg: $arg, arg2: $arg2)
}
```

What I want todo is unmask the `ContainerFragment` data OUTSIDE of the fragment. Usually you can use `@relay(mask: false)`, however the relay compiler errors with the following message:

```
ERROR:
RelayMaskTransform: Cannot unmask fragment spread `PeopleFragment` with arguments. Use the `ApplyFragmentArgumentTransform` before flattening
```

Query that errors:

```
query ChatRefetchContainerRefetchQuery(
      $arg: ID!
      $arg2: Boolean!
    ) {
      ...PeopleFragment
        @arguments(arg: $arg, arg2: $arg2)
        @relay(mask: false)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

the only way to fix it is like

`query ChatRefetchContainerRefetchQuery(
      $arg: ID!
      $arg2: Boolean!
    ) {
      Peoples @arguments(arg: $arg, arg2: $arg2) {
         ...PeopleFragment @relay(mask: false)
      }
    }`